# Remove some character in the start and in the end using sed

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to extract word between `"profile "` and `"]"`.

my contents

```
[profile gateway]
[profile personal]
[profile DA]
[profile CX]
```

for this i have tried

```
less ~/.aws/config |grep  "\[profile"|sed  -E 's/\[profile(.)//'
```

which gives

```
gateway]
personal]
DA]
CX]
```

I know can add a pipe and us tr to delete last `"]"` or even cut would do but can someone help me with above sed command with regex to remove last `"]"`

Comment: I am sure there is a much more efficient/complex solution but you can try using 3 sed commands in one: `sed -E 's/\[//;s/\]//;s/profile //'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **use `sed`**:

```sh
sed -n 's/.*\[profile *\([^][]*\).*/\1/p' ~/.aws/config
```

*Details*:

- `-n` - suppress default line output
- `.*\[profile *\([^][]*\).*/`  - find any text, `[profile`, zero or more spaces, then capture into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`, and then match the rest of the text
- `\1` - replace with Group 1 value
- `p` - print the result of the substitution.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/FwGPvl):

```sh
s='[profile gateway]
[profile personal]
[profile DA]
[profile CX]'
sed -n 's/.*\[profile *\([^][]*\).*/\1/p' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
gateway
personal
DA
CX
```

**With a GNU `grep`**

```sh
grep -oP '(?<=\[profile )[^]]+' ~/.aws/config
```

The `(?<=\[profile )[^]]+` regex matches a location that is immediately preceded with `profile`  string and then matches one or more chars other than `]`. `-o` option makes `grep` extract the matches only and `P` enables the PCRE regex syntax.

**With `awk`**

You may also use `awk`:

```sh
awk '/^\[profile .*]$/{print substr($2, 0, length($2)-1)}' ~/.aws/config
```

It will find all lines that start with `[profile` , and oputput the second field without the last char (that is a `]` char that will get omitted).

Answer (score 3):

If you can use grep with `-P` for a Perl-compatible regular expression:

```
less ~/.aws/config | grep -oP  "\[profile \K[^][]+(?=])"
```

The pattern matches:

- `\[profile`  Match literally
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `[^][]+` Match 1+ times any char except `[` and `]`
- `(?=])` Positive lookahead to assert (not match) `]`

For the example content, the output will be

```
gateway
personal
DA
CX
```

Answer (score 3):

*- - extract word between `profile`  and `]`* means to delete up to `profile`  and from `]` on, ie. `^.*profile`  and `].*$`:

```
$ sed 's/^.*profile \|\].*$//g' file
```

Output:

```
gateway
personal
DA
CX
```

Notice, that if only one boundary is found, it is removed.

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple in `awk`; by making field separators as either as `[profile` OR `]`(as per shown samples) and print the columns as per needed output.

```
awk -F'\\[profile |\\]' '{print $2}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Another shorter `awk` solution:

```sh
awk -F '[] ]' '$1 == "[profile" {print $2}' ~/.aws/config

gateway
personal
DA
CX
```

Answer (score 1):

> `trying to extract word between "profile " and "]"`

Also with `awk` using as condition that `profile` is at the end of `$1`:

```
awk '$1 ~ /profile$/ {sub(/]$/,"",$2);print $2}' file
gateway
personal
DA
CX
```